# SAS sum a particular value

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with value for each day of particular month like `01JAN2020`, `03JAN2020`, `06JAN202`, `01FEB2020`, `04FEB2020`. I need to count rows in particular month year. When I use `count(*)` function and group it by particular column I received only daily rows counting. Which function will show the sum of rows number in particular month rather than daily sum.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

In SQL in order to compute an aggregate count for the months of the dates, the `GROUP BY` should be by the date's month.  The month (or 1st day of the month) can be computed using the `INTNX` function, or the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions.

**Proc SQL**

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2021); * initialize random number stream;

  do date = '01jan2020'd to today();
    do _n_ = 1 to rand('integer', 5);  * random, up to 5 repeats per day;
      output;
    end;
  end;

  format date date9.;
run;

proc sql; 
  create table want as
  select 
    intnx('month', date, 0) as month format=yymon7.
  , count(*) as count
  from
    have
  group by
    calculated month /* calculated is SAS SQL special feature */
  ;
```

[image]

---

**Proc MEANS**

You can also use `Proc MEANS` and format the date as a month representation.  The procedure will *group* according to the formatted value.

Example:

```
proc means nway data=have noprint ;
  format date yymon7.;
  class date;
  var date;
  output out=want N=count;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PROC FREQ + a format for how you want your date displayed. The first example is by year month, the second is just by month name.

```
   *by year month;
   proc freq data=sashelp.stocks;
   format date yymmn6.;
   table date;
   run;
   
   *by month name;
   proc freq data=sashelp.stocks;
   format date monname.;
   table date;
   run;
```